# tex4ht problems with footnotes

Tags: footnotes, tex4ht

I have a problem with footnotes and tex4ht. The following document has a wrong next pointer in subsection 1 and a bad previous pointer in subsection 3:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chap}
\section{A}
\subsection{aa}
xxx\footnote{A}yyy
\subsection{ab}
text
\subsection{ac}
text
\end{document}
```

The command I use to generate html files is: `htlatex main xhtml,4,next`. To reproduce: open main.html and click on 1.1.1 "aa" and then click on "next" to go to 1.1.3 (instead of 1.1.2).

When running the above command a second time, everything works fine. What is the correct way to get a sane document at the first run? That is with a directory that contains only the `.tex` file and no intermediate files?

Comment: Just an observation: I don't know about tex4ht, but I just rendered your example to html using plastex and it behaves correctly on the first run.  http://plastex.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I took the liberty to open a bug at [the tex4ht bug database](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?197). I will report here any informations from the devs others than a bug fix.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is there is no way to get a sane document at the first run.

LaTeX is designed to be run two times (at least) to create a correct document structure. At the first run, LaTeX produces files which will be use the second time to create a correct structure.

This is not a tex4ht issue.

Comment: by default, tex4ht run latex three times, to get correct links. it seems in this particular case even three runs are not enough, as on second tex4ht run (after 6 latex runs!), links are correct

Comment: Indeed ! sorry for the mistake. So, it seems to me it's a bug inside tex4ht. Perhaps tex4ht dev should be interested by this post.