# How to lower the superscripts (and raise the subscripts)

Tags: fonts, xetex, subscripts, superscripts, unicode-math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tex4ht problems with footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50089/tex4ht-problems-with-footnotes)

I am preparing a document using XeLaTeX, `unicode-math` and Asana Math OTF (turned on by `\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}`).  I've noticed that subscripts are located very low (and superscripts very high).  I'd like to change this behavior.  I know (e.g., from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5199/5626)) that `\fontdimen`s might be the way to go; however, I have no experience with them (even in vanilla (e)TeX, not to mention XeTeX).  So my question is: how to do it?  In particular, how to set `\fontdimens`s of a given font in Xe(La)TeX, and what values would you recommend for Asana?

Comment: AFAIK setting the extended font dimensions is ineffective in XeTeX (they don't actually get applied), so you can do this only in LuaTeX (`\Umathsupshiftup=12pt`).

Comment: I believe the following thread might be helpful: [Redefine the default depth of superscript and subscript document-wide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46549/redefine-the-default-depth-of-superscript-and-subscript-document-wide)