# How to use Palatino-like math fonts in XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, mathpazo

After some [fighting with Asana Math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50585/5626), I thought that I could give a Palatino-like math font a chance.  So the questions are: (1) what exactly is the difference between `pxfonts` and `mathpazo` and (2) how to enable these in XeLaTeX (`\usepackage{mathpazo}` seemed to break text font, which is Linux Libertine using `fontspec`; in case this is relevant, I can provide a MWE)?

Comment: Load fontspec *after* mathpazo or pxfonts. In the second case you probably will have to use  the `[no-math]` option of fontspec.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to load 'traditional' font packages and `fontspec`, load the latter first as it automatically loads either Latin Modern or Computers Modern, depending on the package options given.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

However, I would favour loading `mathpazo` purely for the math bits-and-pieces, and load TeX Gyre Pagella (their Palatino clone) as an OTF

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\setmainfont
     [ BoldFont       = texgyrepagella-bold.otf ,
       ItalicFont     = texgyrepagella-italic.otf ,
       BoldItalicFont = texgyrepagella-bolditalic.otf ]
     {texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\[ y = mx + c \]
\end{document}
```

(I've taken a 'defensive' position with the font, and loaded using the file names as installed by TeX Live in the `texmf` tree. If you have the font installed for general use in your system font folder, it should load fine by name.)

Comment: Late comment, but why would you prefer Gyre Pagella to `mathpazo`?

Comment: @Dennis `mathpazo` is a 'virtual font', built up from various bits and pieces to give (reasonably) good coverage of glyphs. The TeX Gyre project have worked to have a more 'consistent' font where various gaps/issues in the URW Palatino clone (used by `mathpazo`) are addressed. The Gyre font covers text mode, so loading `mathpazo` for math mode is still useful. (You could also consider using `unicode-math` and the TeX Gyre Palladio math font.)

Comment: Just tried this example, and strangely, it built with `lualatex`, but `xelatex` failed with `fontspec error: "font-not-found"` like in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118944/xelatex-does-not-find-texgyreterms. I looked up `texgyrepagella-regular.otf` on my system, and I could only find it in `~/.fonts`?! So, turns out I had to `tlmgr install tex-gyre` before I could run this example. Cheers!